# C# and XML: Running sum of child nodes

Tags: c#, xml

Ok so I have a list of data generated into an XML file.
Here it is: http://pastebin.com/cnF9bQqf

Essentially, in C# I want to loop through some particular child nodes and get a value.

Firstly, the total price. So the  node. There are three values in this xml file and I want to loop through and add them up.

Secondly, count the number of room qualities. <\Quality>. So in this list there is 1 Standard, and 2 Premiums and I want to be able to loop through the list and count these :)

I'm not quite sure where to even begin :S

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LINQ to XML` to get all `Room_Price` elements, then use Sum method:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");
var sum = xDoc.Descendants("Room_Price").Select(x => (int)x).Sum();
```

For `Qualities`, you could use a Dictionary:

```
var qualities = xDoc.Descendants("Quality")
      .GroupBy(x => (string)x)
      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

`qualities["Premium"]` will give the value of `2`.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, I get an error underneath xDocument, first line. I'm not sure how to reference my document?